# yii2 swiftmailer link does not work

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

I'd like to add link to a message, but link can't be clicked in the message.. I put it this way.

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                    ->setTo($user->email)
                    ->setFrom('my@yandex.ru')
                    ->setSubject($model->name)
                    ->setHtmlBody($model->preview ."<p><a href='".  Url::to('/site/more/'. $model->id) ."'> Article</a></p><p><a href='".  Url::to('/site/more/'. $user->id) ."'> Unsubscribe</a></p>")
                    ->send();
```

How can I add working link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply use an absolute url, e.g. :

```
Url::to(['site/more', 'id' => $model->id], true)
```

Read more about [Url::to()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to()-detail).